# Adding System.Web.WebPages dll to bin folder of 80 in IIS gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when run the portal

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2013, .net-4.8, antiforgerytoken, csrf-token

I am trying to fix CSRF issue, i have added AntiForgery.Validate() method in the button click event. To implement CSRF, I need System.Web.Helpers namespace which is in System.Web.WebPages dll, so it was also added in the reference. When I publish and deploy it to IIS, System.Web.WebPages dll was added to Sharepoint 80 bin folder. When I run the application, it shows an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.
[This is the error when i run the portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hguK.png)
[This is dll available in bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgJGo.png)

I am trying to fix CSRF issue, i have added AntiForgery.Validate() method in the button click event. To implement CSRF, I need System.Web.Helpers namespace which is in System.Web.WebPages dll, so it was also added in the reference. When I publish and deploy it to IIS, System.Web.WebPages dll was added to Sharepoint 80 bin folder. When I run the application, it should show the "Request Antiforgery token and its value" but i see the error.

Comment: could you assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the folder where you have placed he dll file i can see it is placed at the virtual directory. try setting iis app pool identity to the network service. add <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="True"> in the web.config file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, thanks for the information. I have tried all three things you suggested but still, have the same error.

Comment: This is the code:   protected void btnUserStatusEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AntiForgery.Validate();
            PopulateUserStatusDetails(MMIMembership.GetUserStatusDetails(EnteredUser));
            pnlEditUserContainer.Visible = false;
            pnlUserStatusUpdate.Visible = true;
            rwndEditUser.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;           
            lblUpdateUserStatus.Visible = false;
            lblUserStatus.Text = string.Empty;
        }